# How to use models in Vue watch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have simple Vue component which looks like this:

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            brands: [],
            models: [
                {id:1, name: 'one'},
                {id:2, name: 'two'},
                {id:3, name: 'tree'}
            ],

            filters: {},

            filter: {
                brand: null,
                model: null,
                price: null,
                year: null
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'filter.brand': (brand) => {
            console.log('filter.brand', this, this.models)

            socket.emit('brands.models.get', brand, (models) => {
                console.log(models)

                console.log(this.models)

                this.models = models;

                console.log(this.models)
            })
        },
    }
}
```

The main problem is that when I receive data from socket I cant see models.

For example `console.log(this.models)` returns undefined.

Here what full print looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using normal functions for watchers :

```
 'filter.brand': function(){}
```

Because arrow functions : [ **(brand) => {}** ] do not have their own "this", I'm guessing that's causing the problem.

PS: This is what your code should look like in order to work properly :

```
   'filter.brand': function(brand){
        //Access to the vue instance
        var me = this;

        socket.emit('brands.models.get', brand, (models) => {
            me.models = models;
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Method Definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), as commonly shown for Vue `created()` and `mounted()` methods, ref [Vue.Js Examples - created](http://vuejsexamples.net/vuejs-created/),

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, a shorter syntax for method definitions on objects initializers is introduced.

```js
  created() {
    this.filter.brand = 'f'
  },
  watch: {
    'filter.brand'(brand) {
      console.log('filter.brand', this, this.models)
    },
  }
```

Example, [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/YYpmmv?q=vue&limit=mine)